# Abstract Generics and List of abstract

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I haven't found my use case in the existing questions so here I go.
I have an abstract class that has generics like this :

```
public abstract class aParameter<T>
{
    private T _parameter;

    public T Parameter
    {
        get { return _parameter;}
    }

    ...
}
```

Then I have my "Type" classes like this :

```
public class IntParameter : aParameter<Int32>
{
    public IntParameter(Int32 value)
    {
        _parameter = value;
    }
}

 public class TextParameter : aParameter<String>
{
    public TextParameter(String value)
    {
        _parameter = value;
    }
}
```

Now in my application code, I'd like to create a dictionary with the abstract generic class without specifying the generic type. Like this :

```
...
private Dictionary<Int32, aParameter> _paramDict = new Dictionary<Int32, aParameter>();
...
```

In a previous version, I used interfaces instead of abstract class for `aParameter` but I wanted to migrate it to abstract so that I could simplify my "Type" classes and not repeat identical code for each "Type".

Any thoughts here?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that it will be part of a library that is meant to be distributed among the company so I really need to secure the allowed types. I can't allow for just `objects` to be fed into my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably still going to need the non-generic interface (or nongeneric abstract base class as Brandon says), unless you drop to working with objects.

The reason is that `aParameter<String>` is not the same type as `aParameter<int32>` so you'll not be able to get them into the one dictionary without some help.

My preferred method around this is to declare a non-generic interface and use that as the basis for the dictionary, then implement it in each of your typed generics, and also in an abstract base class. That way you can inherit from the base class where possible, or just implement the interface if one of your types needs to inherit from something else - you get maximum flexibility.

Comment: The interface method looks like my choice. I'm still crashing into an issue as I need the `public T Parameter` available from the interface. I tried putting it as `public Object Parameter` but then can't override the output type. I'll see if I can go with the `object` output

Comment: Ok done it this way with the `object` return type for my `Parameter` property and the results are fine. Now to finish cleaning up the code ...

Comment: You could have the interface return object for the parameter return type, but still have it more strongly typed in the generic.

Comment: How? I tried but I shouts out that I don't implement the interface `Parameter` properly when I try to type it as `T Parameter` in the abstract generic class...

Answer (score 5):

Make a non-generic abstract base class and have your generic abstract class inherit from it.

Comment: Nice but I prefer Jon's `interface` way of doing it.

Comment: Yep, Jon gave you the best of both worlds :)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of generic types is (among other things) that you can only write code once that can be used for multiple types. However, as C# is strongly types, the compiler needs to know what types it is dealing with in the generic class. This is why you have to specify the type of the generic (i.e. the type in angled brackets)
If you don't specify the type of the generic then, in your example, the compiler wouldn't know the type of the Parameter property.

Depending on exactly what you're doing with it, there are a number of possible approaches:

1. Use a `Dictionary<int, object>`.
   When reading the values, you can use a bunch of if/elses to check the specific type of the object and convert to the appropriate type. e.g.

   if(obj.GetType() == typeof(TextParameter)) 
   {
       TextParameter p = obj as TextParameter
       // Do stuff
   } 
   else if obj.GetType() == typeof(IntParameter)) 
   {
       IntParameter p = obj as IntParameter
       // Do stuff
   }
2. Have multiple dictionaries. `Dictionary<int, TextParameter>`, `Dictionary<int, IntParameter>`, etc.
3. If there are methods/properties in aParameter that are not type dependent then move them to a lower level non-generic abstract class. This could give you at least some of your functionality without having to resort to type conversions.

Comment: I can't go for your option 1 as `object`is too generic and I don't want the if/else junk. Your option 2 is not possible either as I don't know what is fed into my code. Your option 3 is probably the best bet, I'll have to figure it out somehow but I'm fed up with casting like hell.