# List of abstract class with generic parameter type?

Tags: c#, abstract-class

Let's say I have these classes:

```cs
public abstract class Thing<T> { }

public class Str : Thing<string> { }

public class Boo : Thing<bool> { }
```

I'd like to create a `List` of `Thing`.

This is an example of what I'd like to do (invalid C# code):

```
new List<Something>()
{
    new Str(),
    new Boo()
};
```

How could I do something like that, would it even be possible?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969405/abstract-generics-and-list-of-abstract) but couldn't seem to correctly understand any of the proposed answers.

Comment: Your List would have be defined as `new List<Thing<string>>()` or `new List<Thing<bool>>()`. If you want to not specify it, you will need to make a new class called Thing that Thing<T> inherits from. You could then have virtual/abstract methods that Thing<T> must override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To satisfy `List<Something>` then `Thing<T>` must inherit `Something`. The answers in the post you linked have the solution: you need to introduce a non-generic base class.

```
public abstract class Something { }
public abstract class Thing<T>: Something { }

public class Str : Thing<string> { }
public class Boo : Thing<bool> { }

new List<Something>()
{
    new Str(),
    new Boo()
};
```

Comment: You wrote the code for Jon's answer (from the post I linked), which is exactly what I needed as I couldn't understand him. Thanks a lot.