# Entity Framework entities with lists of generic abstracts can't be assigned to non-generic base

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, abstract-class

I have found [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969405/abstract-generics-and-list-of-abstract) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62111972/list-of-abstract-class-with-generic-parameter-type) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210632/how-to-have-a-list-of-problembasetresult) [seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066506/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-objects-that-inherit-from-the-same-generic-class-with-v) similar to mine, but I just can't get answers from any of them to work properly.

I have an non-generic abstract base class, a generic base class that inherits from the non-generic one, and some classes that inherit from the generic base class. So far so good.

```
public abstract class BaseTable { }
public abstract class BaseTable<T> : BaseTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
public class Foo { }
public class Bar { }
public class MyFooTable : BaseTable<Foo> { }
public class MyBarTable : BaseTable<Bar> { }
```

When I put these classes to use I can't convert from them to the non-generic base class:

```
public class SomethingThatUsesFoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<MyFooTable> Table { get; set; }
}
public class SomethingThatUsesBar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<MyBarTable> Table { get; set; }

    public void DoIt()
    {
        Something.DoSomething(Table);
        Something.DoSomething<Bar>(Table);
    }
}

public static class Something
{
    public static void DoSomething(IList<BaseTable> table) { }
    public static void DoSomething<T>(IList<BaseTable<T>> table) { }
}
```

The problem is with `DoSomething()` where neither variants work. Both give compiler errors that says `IList<MyBarTable> is not assignable to parameter type IList<BaseTable>`, or `IList<MyBarTable> to IList<BaseTable<Bar>>`).

In this example I could probably get around it by using `public IList<BaseTable> Table { get; set; }` instead, but in my application these are Entity Framework entities with navigation properties and must refer to their proper types:

```
public DbSet<MyFooTable> MyFooTables { get; set; }
public DbSet<MyBarTable> MyBarTables { get; set; }
public DbSet<SomethingThatUsesFoo> FooUsage { get; set; }
public DbSet<SomethingThatUsesBar> BarUsage { get; set; }
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but I've worked myself blind. What can't I see?

Comment: The reason is the non-covariance of IList<T>. If you could pass a list of apples to a list<fruit> you could add oranges to list<apple>. C# doesn' t allow that, we're typesafe. It works in javascript ^^.
If you just need the items of your list and not the list itself, just replace `IList<T>` by `IEnumerable<T>` and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew Williams pointed out, if you wrap constraints around your type arguments you can get it to work. You will need a type-param for the List that takes the non-generic Base-Class aswell

```
// usage:
    public void DoIt()
    {
        Something.DoSomething(Table);
        Something.DoSomething<Bar, MyBarTable>(Table);
    }

// definition:
    public static void DoSomething<TTable>(IList<TTable> table) 
        where TTable: BaseTable 
     {
     }

    public static void DoSomething<TItem, TTable>(IList<TTable> table) 
        where TTable : BaseTable < TItem>
    {
    }
```

Unfortunately the compiler can't infer the type parameters for the second overload with TItem and TTable, as long there is no argument that refers to TItem in the method signature. If the signature however was e.g. like

```
public static void DoSomething<TItem, TTable>(IList<TTable> table, Func<TItem> itemCreator) 
        where TTable : BaseTable < TItem>
```

(as an example) you would not need to specify the type arguments explictily, and the second call would go like for example this:

```
Something.DoSomething(Table, () => new MyBarTable());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that IList is not covariant (you can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/))

Basically what happens is that with generics inheritance doesn't apply as you would think. For instance IList doesn't inherit from IList<BaseTable>, nor it inherits from IList.

The reason for this is because IList has methods such as Add, and it would be a problem if you can assign IList to IList because then the Add method would accept BaseTable, which means you could add MyFooTable to a IList that was initially of MyBarTable.

All this will make much more sense if you read the article I shared above regarding Covariance / Contravariance.

Now, to solve your code, you need to choose an interface that works for you and is Covariant on T. For instance, IEnumerable, IReadOnlyCollection or IReadOnlyList.

Comment: You also could solve this by making the `DoSomething` method more generic and using a type constraint: `public static void DoSomething<TTable, TItem>(IList<TTable> table) where TTable : BaseTable<TItem>`

Comment: With a covariant solution the interface is read-only. You cannot add items to the table. That might work for the OP, but if not, they will need to use the generic solution